# What's a "ship" called in Japan?

Tags: slang

It's the "ship" from relationship, and generally refers to a romantic or sexual pairing/couple that an individual finds enjoyment from and/or supports. I know about the naming conventions (eg. サスサク), just not what the support is called. eg: 「サスサクは私の好きな何々です。」とか「どれの二人は愛にされていると思いますか。」シップかペアか何かと言って知りません。

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to say "I ship X with Y"? (shipping slang)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97083/how-to-say-i-ship-x-with-y-shipping-slang)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's カップリング or simply CP. Japanese Wikipedia article on the topic: 
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/カップリング_(同人)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0_(%E5%90%8C%E4%BA%BA))

For example, here is some thread where people are talking about 好きなカップリング: http://f-talk.net/others/727/