# How to say "I ship X with Y"? (shipping slang)

Tags: word-choice, words, slang, internet-slang

If you're not familiar, in fandoms, it's common in English to "ship" characters together (essentially meaning you think they should be in a romantic relationship). I know how Japanese ships are usually designated (e.g. Shirona x Hikari = シロヒカ), but I don't know explicitly state something like "I ship Shirona with Hikari". I can work around it and say something like "シロナとヒカリはくっつけばいいと思う" (I think Shirona and Hikari should be together), but I'd like to know if there's a more appropriate anime-otaku slang term I can use here.

Comment: シロナとヒカリって、ポケモンの？

Comment: It depends on whether you want a corresponding Japanese verb, or an idiomatic sentence to express the same thing. I think idiomatic expressions tend to be noun-oriented in Japanese in many cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a "ship" called in Japan?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33341/whats-a-ship-called-in-japan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no phrase that is as short as "ship", but you can say

- AとBをくっつける
- AとBをカップリングする
- A×Bを推す
- A×B推しです / 推しはA×Bです

Comment: what do actual anime/manga fans who are actually japanese say eg 'i totally ship [kei shirogane and moeha fujiwara](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/uffnhv/were_we_supposed_to_ship_kei_x_moeha_after_s02e02/)' in kaguya-sama ?

Comment: @BCLC Doesn't the last bullet work? 圭×萌葉推しです, etc.

Comment: so that's really what, say, naruto fans say eg HinataxNaruto推しです? wait...google translate says 推しです means recommend/favourite/push? errrr according to this shipping in japanese is like 'i recommend kei x moeha', 'i push for kei x moeha' or 'i favour kei x moeha' ?

Comment: @BCLC It's absurd to trust Google Translate to find the meaning of net slang. Please do your own research first before asking me here.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer since I can't tell you how to use it as a verb but the noun 'ship' in this sense is カップリング or shortened to CP

Comment: what do actual anime/manga fans who are actually japanese say eg 'i totally ship [kei shirogane and moeha fujiwara](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/uffnhv/were_we_supposed_to_ship_kei_x_moeha_after_s02e02/)' in kaguya-sama ?